# Работа с компонентами из другого layout-файла

Tags: java, android-layout-inflater

Имею несколько xml файлов в проекте для работы через ViewPager. Задача такая - при загрузке приложения в TextView в разных xml грузить разный текст. Попробовал вот так:

```
public class MondayFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_monday,null);

        TextView monday_textView = view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        monday_textView.setText("Hello, Monday");

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_monday, container, false);

        }
}
```

Правильно ли я передаю параметры в TextView?

Comment: не совсем понятно, в чем именно ваша проблема, но из смысла заголовка могу сообщить, что вы не можете изменять виджеты, которые в данный момент отсутствуют на экране. по коду в вопросе: return должен возвращать то, что у вас под именем view, а не новый экземпляр инфлейта разметки с которым не проводилось никаких изменений.

Comment: с этим только начал работать и поэтомуконечно возникают вопросы. Смысл, если по-простому - вставить текст в TextView на других xml-файлах.

Answer (score 0):

Переделал так:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pageAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position){
            Log.d(TAG,"onPageSelected, position = " + position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}

private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        return "Title " + position;
    }
```